# How to properly overload an operator in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, garbage-collection, operators

I have a Vec2 class in kotlin. 
I overloaded the operator `*` like this:

```kotlin
operator fun times(v:Float): Vec2 {
    return Vec2(this.x * v, this.y * v)
}
```

End the behavior is just as I expected, I can use `*` and `*=` to scale the vector

```kotlin
var a = Vec2() * 7f; a *= 2f
```

However, from my understanding what I do here, is I create a new object, by calling `Vec2()`, every time I use `*`
Even if I use `*=` and I do not really need to return anything, as I could just edit the object itself (using `this` keyword)

Is there any way to overload the `*=` operator, so that it has the similar behavior to this function?

```kotlin
fun mul(v:Float) {
    this.x *= v; this.y *= v
}
```

I need my application to run smoothly, and these operators are used quite a lot,
I do not want any lags caused by garbage collector's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a new object, you should just change your x and y to `var`'s so they become reassignable.

Doing this will most likely end you up with something like this:

```
class Vec2(var x: Float, var y: Float) {
    operator fun times(v: Float) {
        x *= v
        y *= v
    }
}
```

Then in your implementation it is as simple as:

```
val a = Vec2(1.0f, 1.0f)
    
a * 2f
// After this line both x and y are 2.0f
```

If you really want to overload the `*=` operator then add the `timesAssign` operator function instead [for more info see the kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#augmented-assignments)

Comment: Worth mentioning, if you overload `timesAssign`, then you'll need to remove the `times` operator overload if you want to be able to use `*=` on a `var`. Otherwise, the compiler won't let you use it. And I'm guessing OP doesn't want to lose the `*` operator functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried the same solution before, unfortunately it's not what I need, the problem with this your solution is that I cannot use it that way: `a = b * c`, as `b` would get overwritten

Comment: You have to choose one behavior or the other. Either `*` mutates the object or it doesn't. In the case of `a = b * c`, when you really do want to create a new object, then you could use a copy function like `a = b.copy() * c`. If you're really concerned about the GC, a solution commonly used in games is object pooling.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I needed :)
`a = b.copy() * c` seems like the best way around to me.

Comment: Isn't having `*` mutate the object likely to be counterintuitive and confusing?  That's not how it behaves for any other types; that's why there's also `*=` which does mutate.